# $x^TAx=0$ for all $x$ when $A$ is a skew symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ skew symmetric matrix.
>
> Show that $x^TAx =0 \ \forall x \in \mathbb R^n$.

How to prove this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You know that $-A=A^T$, so

$x^T A x = (x, Ax)$ (1)

but we also have

$x^T A x = x^T (-A^T) x = -x^T A^T x = -(Ax)^Tx = -(Ax,x)$ (2)

Now notice (1) and (2) need to be the same.

Comment: How do you conclude with that $x^TAx = -x^TAx $ returns 0?

Is it as simple as moving $-x^TAx $ to the left so we end up with:
$2 x^TAx = 0$ and dividing with the scalar 2 on both sides so that:
$ x^TAx = 0$

Comment: @Mollart yes, or, just think about it this way: how can a = -a?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**
$$(x^TAx)^T=x^TA^Tx=-x^TAx$$
and $x^TAx$ is a real(Why?) so...