# Does $x^TAx = \frac{1}{2} x^T(A+A^T)x$ hold for all matrices $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a matrix, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$

Then given any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, does the following identity hold for all matrices $A$?
$$x^TAx = \frac{1}{2} x^T(A+A^T)x$$

My concern is that if $A^T = -A$, then RHS becomes zero, while LHS is nonzero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it holds obviously. Your case with $A^T=-A$ implies also that the left side of the equation is $0$ since $ x^TAx = (x^TAx)^T = x^TA^Tx = -x^TAx$

Answer (score 2):

You are right. It follows from
$$
x^\top A x = (x^\top A x)^\top = x^\top A^\top x.
$$

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is skew-symmetric, then the LHS is also zero - see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358281/xtax-0-for-all-x-when-a-is-a-skew-symmetric-matrix?rq=1).