# Transpose Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

Let A be an $n \times n$ matrix such that $A^T=-A$. Prove that $x^T \cdot A \cdot x = 0$ for all $x \in R^n$. Further, prove that the matrix $I_{n} + A$ is invertible.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Thius is a multiduplicate. See for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358281

Answer (score 2):

$$(x^T\cdot A\cdot x)^T=x^T\cdot A^T\cdot x=-x^T\cdot A\cdot x$$ hence this scalar is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $<,>$ be the scalar product, $<A(x),x>=<x,A^T(x)>=<x,-A(x)>$ implies that $2<A(x),x>=0$.

$<x+A(x),x+A(x)>=0$ implies that $<x,x>+<A(x),A(x)>+2<x,A(x)>=<x,x>+<A(x),A(x)>=0$. Since $<,>$ is a scalar product, you deduce that $<x,x>=0$ and $I_n+A$ is injective and henceforth invertible.

Comment: What do you mean by $ (A(x)) $?

Comment: $A$ defines a linear map on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: I like the 2nd part of the argument but not the way you expressed it.  I would say, $I_n+A$ is injective because $x+Ax=0$ implies $\|x\|^2 + \|Ax\|^2=0$ and hence $x=0$.

Comment: How is $x+Ax=0$?

Comment: @kimchilover how is $ x+Ax=0 $?

Comment: If $I+A$ fails to be injective there exists an $x\ne0$ such that $x+Ax=0$, and then ...