# Prove that $x^TAx=0$ when $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A$ is antisymmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A$ is real antisymmetric matrix which satisfies

$$ A^T=-A $$

Prove that

$$ x^TAx=0, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

Example of real antisymmetric would be:

$$ A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

But other than this i dont know where to begin with this.

Now if someone can provide some insight on this that would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Tuki

Comment: What is the transpose of $x^TAx$?

Comment: $(x^TAx)^T$ but when it comes to computing this honestly i don't know.

Comment: What theorem do you know about the transpose of a product of three matrices?

Comment: @edm i dont know any theorem about this mayby you could provide link ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transpose Matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2399246)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358281

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a classic exercise :$A$  real $n\times n$ antisymmetric if and only if $x^TAx=0$ for all $x\in {\mathbb{R}}^n$. One sense is easy the second (the question asked) follows from $x^T(A+A^T)x=0$ for all $x\in {\mathbb{R}}^n$ which means $A+A^T=0$ because it is real symmetric.

Comment: Please don't answer such a FAQ. Instead, link to one of the previous identical posts.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: use this$x^TAx=(x^TAx)^T=x^TA^Tx=-x^TAx$.

$x^TAx=(x^TAx)^T$ since $x^TAx$ is a scalar.

Comment: my intuition would tell that transpose of transpose is basically back to square one meaning it doesn't do anything. So how does this work ? $$ (x^TAx)^T=x^TA^Tx $$. My intuition tells me that $$ (x^TAx)^T=xA^Tx^T $$ this would be the correct solution. I'm probably missing some theory ?

Comment: oh it's actually the same thing. $x$ is just on the other side on first equation which doesn't matter ?

Comment: $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$.

Comment: So it does matter if $A$ and $B$ are matrices. $AB$ is of course different from $BA$ but $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$ which is in reverse order.

Comment: $(ABC)^T$ would be $C^TB^TA^T$ ?

Comment: $(ABC)^T=(A(BC))^T=(BC)^TA^T=C^TB^TA^T$.

Comment: Okey this makes sense now. Proving that $x^TAx=0$ applies when $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$ is basically combining these two: $$A^T=-A$$ $$x^TAx=0$$ right ?

Comment: I think i need some more help. I don't know what i am suppose to do here. This is what i have tried so far.
$$ x^TAx=x^TA^T x $$
since
$$ A^T=-A $$
$$ x(-A)x=0 $$

I've tried some other things too but this seemed the most promising one.  Mayby another hint ?

Comment: Please don't answer such a FAQ. Instead, link to one of the previous identical posts.