# Trying to proof that skew-symmetric matrix $x^TAx=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Skew-symmetric matrix is defined as:
$$ A^T=-A $$
Where matrix $A$ is real antisymmetric matrix.

Proof that $$x^TAx=0, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

### My progress so far

$$
x^TAx=0
$$
because $A^T=-A$
$$
(x^TAx)^T=-x^TAx
$$
because $(ABC)^T=(A(BC))^T=(BC)^TA^T=C^TB^TA^T$ ja $(A^T)^T=A$
$$
x^TA^Tx=-x^TAx
$$
$$
x^TA^Tx+x^TAx=0
$$

If someone can spot what i am doing wrong here that would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Tuki

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $x^TAx=0$ when $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A$ is antisymmetric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2481797/prove-that-xtax-0-when-x-in-mathbbrn-and-a-is-antisymmetric) Please do not repost. Instead, edit that previous post of yours to improve it (and delete this one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your difficulty lies in the fact that you never used (2) below, which you can do "for free" because of (1), since then $x^TAx = (x^TAx)^T$; that is, $1 \times 1$ matrices are symmetric.  If you throw this fact in the mix, the demonstration is straightforward:

$x^TAx \in \Bbb R, \tag 1$

so

$x^TAx = (x^TAx)^T = x^TA^T(x^T)^T = x^TA^Tx; \tag 2$

but since

$A^T = -A, \tag 3$

(2) becomes

$x^TAx = -x^TAx, \tag 4$

which implies

$x^TAx = 0. \tag 5$

Comment: You mean $A^t=A$ ???

Comment: You mean equation (3), $A^T = -A$?

Comment: No Robert I meant this $x^TAx = (x^TAx)^T = x^TA^T(x^T)^T = x^TA^Tx; \tag 2$

Comment: This equation doesn't say $A^T = A$.

Comment: Can you explain why you can state the first equality ? about the transpose

Comment: @Isham:. yes; it's in my first sentence; $x^TAx$ is $1 \times 1$, the only entry is the ${}_{11}$ entry.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the result is a scalar, therefore it also equals to its transpose, combining with your result, then you are done.